# Objective c - Canceling operations in NSOperationQueue

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, afnetworking

I'm using `AFNetworking` `AFHTTPClient` just for the example, but this question is about `NSOperationQueue` in general.

The `AFHTTPClient` manage an `NSOperationQueue` for requests made by the client.

It also has a `cancelAllOperations` method that iterate over the `self.operationQueue.operations` and call `[operation cancel]` for each one.

**If I understand this right, it will cancel all the operations waiting in the queue - meaning the operation that didn't started yet, but what with the operations that are currently running? they won't be cancelled??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's documentation

> For currently executing operations, cancel means that the operation
>   object’s work code must check the cancellation state, stop what it is
>   doing, and mark itself as finished. For operations that are queued but
>   not yet executing, the queue must still call the operation object’s
>   start method so that it can processes the cancellation event and mark
>   itself as finished.
>
> An operation remains in its queue until it reports that it is finished
>   with its task. Finishing its task does not necessarily mean that the
>   operation performed that task to completion. An operation can also be
>   canceled. Canceling an operation object leaves the object in the queue
>   but notifies the object that it should abort its task as quickly as
>   possible. For currently executing operations, this means that the
>   operation object’s work code must check the cancellation state, stop
>   what it is doing, and mark itself as finished. For operations that are
>   queued but not yet executing, the queue must still call the operation
>   object’s start method so that it can processes the cancellation event
>   and mark itself as finished.

Comment: Yes but the question is if I iterate over the operationQueue.operations will that include the "currently executing operations"? I suppose that when an operation starts it get dequeue, no? so thats means it won't be in the operationQueue.operations when I call cancel, and it won't get canceled no?

Comment: An operation remains in its queue until it reports that it is finished
with its task.